# How to get Keycloak extra realm's user session on my java spring project not using Adapter

Tags: java, keycloak

```
 Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder
            .builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .clientId("demoapp")
            .build();


    RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm("springboot");

    System.out.println(realmResource);
```

I want to check keycloak extra realm called "springboot" user session on my javaspring boot project.

Comment: What do you want to check exactly? Are you in an OAuth2 client or an OAuth2 resource server?

Comment: I am new in Keycloak and Java Spring. Could you let me know you contact info to explain more. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I think, I am in OAuth client.